# Why does Lord Dorwin's speech impediment disappear here?

Tags: foundation

In part II, chapter 4 of Foundation by Isaac Asimov, we meet the character of Lord Dorwin. Lord Dorwin has a speech impediment (later implied to be voluntary): he says "w" instead of "r" (much like Pontius Pilate in Life of Brian).

However, at least in my copy of the book, one of the first lines that we hear coming out of his mouth is

> A gweat achievement, this Encyclopedia of yoahs, Hahdin. A feat, indeed, to rank with the most majestic accomplishments of all time.

He says "rank" instead of "wank" here. Why? At what level did Dorwin's speech impediment disappear for that one word? Is it Dorwin who doesn't want to say it? Is it the narrator? The author? The publisher? Or just a typo? Is there any way to know?

Comment: Suffice it to say, the fact that he says "rank" rather than "wank" made me pay a lot more attention to that one word than I otherwise would have.

Comment: ha, hadn't noticed that he didn't say wank. It's the same way in my Kindle version

Comment: Initial "r" is not realized the same way as final "r" or intermediate "r." Does he replace initial "r" with "w" in any context?

Comment: @Adamant A few lines down (on the same page in my copy) he says "The lack of the most elementawy wequiahments of a cultuahed gentleman". And then a little further down "Weally, I'm othahwise concuhned."

Comment: Carelessness....

Comment: Because publishing profanities might not be a good idea?  I wonder if it's different between different editions,  what version are you looking at? edit: it was ''Rank" in 'Astounding Science Fiction' 'Volume 28, Issue 6 1942" I think that was the first time it was published. Not leaving us much scope for interesting answers.

Comment: @JeffUK "It seems to have always been that way" is at least somewhat interesting, I think. To me that hints that it was at least on purpose by Asimov. I think mine is the Barnes & Noble Leatherbound Classics Series from 2011. At least that's the only online hit I found with the same cover. Can't find B&N mentioned on the copyright page, only Del Ray, Random House and Bantam Spectra (no idea how those are related). Maybe they did a separate release of basically the same edition?

Comment: Hmm. Yes, interesting. Is the version of the word with an initial "w" (a common, but extremely vulgar, word in *British* English) common in US English? Or, perhaps more importantly, was it when the book was originally published?